# asp.net signalr with Salesforce

Tags: c#

I am creating a real time application in asp.net core to show any new account created in salesforce. I am thinking of using signalR for push notification. Also I want to use signalR to send a response back to salesforce after it has received a push notfication. Am I on the right track.

Comment: Asking *"Am I on the right track?"* isn't really on topic according to the guidelines in the [help]. The format here is specific questions about your implementation if you get stuck. The question you have posed here is mostly opinion based and fairly open ended.

Answer (score 1):

Salesforce natively supports the Bayeux protocol, also commonly called CometD. You can get a C# library to implement a listener, then use the Streaming API or Platform Events to send the notifications. This is the recommended path. SignalR would be more useful if you wanted to provide real-time notifications to a client from your application (e.g a web browser).